# "Most everyone" versus "mostly everyone"?

Tags: adverbs, quantifiers

Saying "most everyone" is much more popular [in books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mostly%20everyone%2C%20most%20everyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmostly%20everyone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20everyone%3B%2Cc0) than "mostly everyone".

> To compute the distance between two coordinates **most everyone/mostly everyone** uses the Spherical Law of Cosines equation.

Which expression should I use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've left out the most important alternative: *almost*. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+everyone%2Cmostly+everyone%2Cmost+everyone&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmost%20everyone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmostly%20everyone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20everyone%3B%2Cc0)'s an expanded version of your Google Ngram:
[image]
In *most everyone*, *most* is a contracted version of *almost*, an adverb modifying the *every* component of *everyone*. (Yes, I know *everyone* is written as one word, but syntactically it's apprehended as a 'pronominal' version of *every*. *Any(one)* works the same way.)

*Most everyone* and *mostly everyone* are colloquial variants; I advise you to avoid them in formal registers.

Comment: I suspect that a lot of those "mostly everyones" are spurious, from sentences along the lines of "Sometimes, there are fights but, mostly, everyone gets along."  (That is, they mean "most of the time, everyone", rather than "almost everyone".)

Answer (score 11):

**Most everyone** is better than **mostly**, because **everyone** is a pronoun, which the [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(linguistics)) **most** can modify. I should note, however, that a by far better option is **[almost](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76636/2127)**, because **most** is a colloquial variant.

A pronoun works like a noun. See how the quantifier **mostly** modifies a noun:

> **Most** *desserts* are sweet.

---

**Mostly** is not a [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(linguistics)) but an [adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb). An adverb usually modifies a verb, an adverb, or an adjective, so it would not modify the pronoun **everyone** (an adverb can modify a *noun phrase*, but it's very hard [for an adverb to modify a pronoun](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76622/can-an-adverb-modify-nouns-pronouns)).

An example from  [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly):

> We **mostly** *stayed* on the beach. (We stayed on the beach for the majority of the time.)

See, the adverb **mostly** modifies the verb *stayed*.

In your example, it's hard to imagine what exactly would **mostly** modify. We'd need to move it closer to the verb **uses**.

> To compute the distance between two coordinates everyone **mostly uses** the Spherical Law of Cosines equation.

---

P.S. Thanks to the commenters for most gallantly reminding me that **most** is unwelcome in most situations where informal English is a no-no.

Comment: You mean 'mostly everyone...' is *incorrect?*

Comment: @MaulikV - I guess yes, because an adverb needs a verb, an adjective, or an adverb to modify. It cannot modify a pronoun.

Comment: Ah! ***Almost everyone** would agree on that!"*; ***"Hardly anyone** knows about this weird use!"*

Comment: @MaulikV - yes, it's okay, since **everyone** and **anyone** are pronouns (they basically work as nouns).

Comment: Should it be noted that while "Most everyone" is *better* than "mostly everyone", it's not actually *good English*? You can use "Most people", "almost all people" or "almost everyone", but you shouldn't use "Most everyone". You could try making it "most of everyone", but that doesn't sound great.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one so far has mentioned the distinction between American and British English. American English tends to use "most" instead of "almost". The OP's original example sentence would not appear in a British-published book; it would state "almost everyone uses...."

Comment: @Nefrubyr - Ah ha! Perhaps, being British myself, that's why I dislike "most everyone". That said, the internet agrees with me: check out the top three hits from googling "most everyone": [1](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/most-vs-almost/), [2](http://www.englishessaywritingtips.com/2011/09/common-errors-in-spoken-english-most-everyone/) and [3](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/06/is-most-almost-there.html). All three are against its usage, to varying degrees.

Comment: I don't think it's even true to say 'American English tends to use "most" instead of "almost"'.   "Most everyone" *is* distinctly American rather than British,  but that doesn't mean it's mainstream American English. Rather, it's colloquial and/or specific to some dialects.

Comment: "Most everyone", while not wrong, is informal and in many situations would be unacceptable in any English speaking country. You've said that a pronoun works like a noun and that "Most desserts are sweet" is correct, but that works because desserts is a plural form of a noun, and can therefore be modified by 'most' You can't say "most lightbulb are bright", and you can't say "most yours are nice", even though lightbulb is a noun and 'yours' is a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

[Just to let you know that the word *most* is also an **adverb!**]

To answer your question,

[WordWebOnline](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=most) has an answer to this:

> ***(of actions or states)*** slightly short of or not quite accomplished; all but

So, when it's something of ***actions/states,*** 'most' is fine.

The example follows:

> *"most everyone agrees"*