# Me personally and I personally

Tags: phrases

In this example (not sure about the punctuation because I heard it):

> When you get a new box, the question is do I keep the box or do I throw the box out - **me personally** I keep it.

How come the object form of **I** is used in the bolded phrase?

Comment: Welcome to the unfettered domain of idiomatic English! It is far from uncommon to hear (and read) the first person objective pronoun used as a subject. "Me and Bob drank some brewskis."

Comment: @P.E.Dant No, that's not what's going on. The subject there is **I**: "*I* keep it"

Comment: @Laurel - Agreed. The *me* is added in  – perhaps as a "conversational colloquialism" added for emphasis? Remove it and the sentence reads just fine.

Comment: @J.R. This is quite a curveball, you must admit, but my comment, aye, it's in error. ;). I spent ten minutes deciding that there is no way to assert with certainty which pronoun the adverb modifies: _I_ or _me._ I dimly recall that there is a name for the role that the phrase "Me personally" plays here (if the reader assumes a comma after the pronoun). Some grammarian or another had a name for the role, and for this kind of phrase. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Also rolled up in this question is the chestnut: what is "personally" here? And does it modify the objective pronoun? After yet another 10 minutes, I invoked _StoneyB's_ **[Ricky's Arrogance Principle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76622/can-an-adverb-modify-nouns-pronouns#comment147783_76628)** and went looking for a wee dram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common way while speaking to add emphasis to the following *I*, in this case to the fact that the speaker actually does something ("I keep it"). I would not use it in writing (except for really casual writing) because it is colloquial.

It can be thought of as an ellipsis of a longer phrase, such as "for me", "as for me", "speaking for me", etc. (Sometimes these words are not elided at all.) In linguistics, it’s just called [left dislocation](https://www.englishforums.com/English/LeftRightDislocationConstructions/bxqhlp/amp.htm).

These examples from the internet should help:

> - [For me personally, I'd be blunt about it.](http://whisper.sh/whisper/050e856c6d7f2410781206d6e548ad0a22d200/For-me-personally-Id-be-blunt-about-it-Its-going-to-be-hard-but-it)
> - [And speaking for me personally, I’d rather pay the projected $1,500 in higher taxes than the $4,500 I’ve gone out of pocket so far this year.](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2017/6/5/1669110/-There-is-no-reason-for-the-health-insurance-industry-to-exist-examples-from-my-own-life)
> - [Me? I personally stopped using a screen years ago.](https://www.facebook.com/dndmemes/photos/a.735357799861056.1073741828.735346629862173/877623852301116/)
> - [Me, I'm All Smiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me,_I%27m_All_Smiles)